# Stop UFW blocking input from docker network

Tags: docker, ufw

I'm using docker and ufw. 
I added the following to the file /etc/ufw/after.rules:

```
*filter 
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0] 
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0] 
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 10.0.0.0/8 
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 172.16.0.0/12 
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 192.168.0.0/16 

-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-user-forward 

-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 192.168.0.0/16 
-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 10.0.0.0/8 
-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 172.16.0.0/12 
-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 192.168.0.0/16 
-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 10.0.0.0/8 
-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 172.16.0.0/12 

-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN 
COMMIT
```

It's from this [site](https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker). This is working and I can acces my sites on port 80 and 443. I have two applications who should communicate through the public domain. So application a is trying to connect to https://appb.mydomain.de but it is not working. I think it is not working because ufw is blocking the connection.

This is the log entry:

```
Nov 20 21:49:37 test kernel: [1734126.807194] [UFW BLOCK] IN=br-d4ae9febff15 OUT= PHYSIN=vethea6c129 MAC=02:42:78:ff:3a:25:02:32:ad:18:00:08:08:00 SRC=172.24.0.8 DST=95.214.42.122 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=21125 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34675 DPT=443 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

d4ae9febff15 is the name of the docker network application a is conntected to.

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
d4ae9febff15        test                bridge              local
```

ufw status:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

80/tcp                     ALLOW FWD   Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW FWD   Anywhere                  
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6)
```

Application b can reach application a through the docker network without any problems. But application a is also reachable from the outside (for example https://appA.mydomain.de). So app b should be able to reach this app but ufw is blocking this.
How can I tell ufw to allow this kind of connections?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make communication between two containers, you need to create a custom bridge network

```
sudo docker network create -d bridge <network_name>
```

Then attach both the container with the same network that you have created with the above command.
For my project, I have added this in my *docker-compose.yml* file. for both containers

```
network_mode: network_name
```

you don't need to do anything with ufw. It is just a firewall that manages your ports.

Comment: Yeah I know that. They are both connected to one network. But they are also both reachable from the outside (https://appA.mydomain.de). So application b should also be able to connect to application a through the public domain. And this is not working because of ufw I guess.

Comment: Is that URL is working for you? appA.mydomain.de. because for me it is giving *site can't be reached*. Can you tell me on which ports you are running your docker containers? Have you opened those ports in your host machine?

Comment: well this is just an example. I don't want to post the right domain. The application is reachable. I can call the api without any problems or open the frontend with my browser. There is a reverse proxy in front of the container so only port 80 and port 443 are open.